# Lebesgue's monotone convergence Theorem Explanation (baby rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $E\in \mathfrak{M}$, let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable
>   functions such that : $$ 0 \leq f_1(x) \leq f_2(x) \leq ...$$ Let $f$
>   be defined by $$ f_n(x) \to f(x)$$ Then  $$ \int_E f_n d\mu \to \int_Ef d\mu$$

The proof begins by asserting that $\int_Ef_nd\mu \to \alpha$. Now, my question is, how do we know that $\alpha$ is not infinity? If it is infinity, do we run into any problems? E.g. if $f_n$ tends to $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ on the set $E = \{ x: x> 0\}$, do we run into any issues with this part of the proof?

Comment: The MCT works if $\alpha = \infty.$

Comment: Note that $f_n \leq f$ for each $n=1,2,...$, so by monotonicity of the integral $\int_E f_n d\mu \leq \int_E f d\mu$. Then $\alpha \leq \int_E f d\mu \leq \infty$. If it happens that $\alpha = \infty$ then the desired result $\int_E f d\mu = \infty = \alpha$ is immediate.